# How can I see if an array in Java contains all the elements of another array?

Tags: java, arrays

Write a boolean function that takes two unordered char arrays as
parameters. The size of the first array is guaranteed to be less than or
equal to the size of the second array. The function returns true if
every element in the first array is contained in the second.

Results:

```
Array One           Array Two           Return
"a"                 "a"                 True
"aa"                "ab"                False
"cbb"               "abbc"              True
"abbccdd"           "abbcccdd"          True
```

*EDIT* Here's my attempt so far:

```
public static Boolean cmprStr( String s1, String s2 )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++ )
    {
        if( !s2.contains( String.valueOf( s1.charAt(i) ) ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you done so far? Where is your attempt?

Comment: That's easy, you just have to check if every element in One exists in Two. Think on how would you do that if you have a box with... colors, and you have to know if every color in box   `A` exists in box `B`. How would you do that in real life ( with real objects ) ? Once you have that, coding is the easy part.

Comment: Shamoon, Strings are **not** arrays in Java, think on rephrasing your question before it gets closed.

Comment: You're taking Strings as argument - the exercise specifies char arrays (there's a difference!) So you shouldn't have String parameters but char[]parameters, and instead of String.contains() you need array accesses and the == operator.

Comment: The problem here is repetition. If you look at the second result row, it returns false because the first "a" was already accounted for

Comment: @Shamoon:  Try using a `Map<Character, Integer>` to maintain a count of how often a character appears in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it!!!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class stringClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        char s1[] = { 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd' };
        char s2[] = { 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd' };

        Boolean ret = cmprStr( s1, s2 );

        System.out.println( ret );
    }

    public static Boolean cmprStr( char[] s1, char[] s2 )
    {
        char subS2[] = new char[s1.length];
        int cnt = 0;

        Arrays.sort( s1 );
        Arrays.sort( s2 );

        for( int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++ )
        {
            for( int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++ )
            {
                if( s1[i] == s2[j] )
                {
                    subS2[cnt++] = s1[i];
                    s2[j] = ' ';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if( Arrays.equals( s1, subS2 ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are four steps that might help you to solve these kind of problems.

1. First understand what the problem is.
2. Identify functions and variables
3. Think on how would you do that in real life
4. Code it.

The last part is the easiest one.

As for step 3:

Let's say you have a box with:

```
A = [a,b,b,c,c,d,d]
```

And other with:

```
B = [a,b,b,c,c,c,d,d]
```

How would you go ( in real life ) if you want to know if all the elements in A exist in B?

Well you:

1. Take the first element ( a )
2. Look for it in in B
3. If it exists, you're right on track ( OK = true ).
4. If it doesn't you end with OK = false
5. Repeat until you finish with all the elements.

As absurd as this may look, this is the first step to code.

Now take each step and create a pseudo-code for it ( not real Java code )

```
//1. Take the first element ( a )  
    e = A[0]
//2. Look for it in in B
    for each x in B do  
       if x == b  found = true 
    end
    found = false 
//3. If it exists, you're right on track ( OK = true ).
    if found == true ? OK = true continue... 
//4. If it doesn't you end with OK = false
    else OK = false  
//5. Repeat until you finish with all the elements.
     go to 1.- using A[1]

Check the value of "OK" at the end and that will be your answer.
```

Once you have this part correct and complete ( **notice** my pseudo-code *may* be wrong, you have to check it for your self )  then you're in position to code and that'll be very straightforward.

Later, when you have completely understood this process, you may skip the part of writing down the algorithm and you'll be ready for what Andrew Lazarus mention, you can search for better algorithms to optimize your search.

But, try to solve it this way first.

Good luck

Comment: Posting pseudo code that misses the most important part of the problem (which isn't trivially solvable with that approach)? ;) The algorithm won't work for A:"aa" and B:"ab" - the other bug is easily fixed, but that one seems harder..

Comment: @Voo not really, the pseudo code is not giving the answer, but a way of **THINKING** for your self, very valuable aspect for anyone who wants to learn to program. I also notice that my algorithm is wrong upfront )

Comment: Sure but I think that'll confuse the poor guy more then help - but then I'm a horrible teacher to start with, so I'm surely not the best one to discuss this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is a homework tag missing?

Because of the way that repetitions are handled, I think you should convert *both* arrays into `Map<Character, Integer>` with counts. (Actually, if you know the input is a `char` between 'a' and 'z', it is better to use an array of `int` for performance, but I will leave optimization up to you.) Once this step is done, you just go through the smaller array and check that the count is ≤ the corresponding count in the larger one.

Comment: Sure, for my usual rate of $90/hour.

Comment: +1 for the only one using a correct algorithm, although already a bit too optimized for a beginner imho ;)

Comment: @Voo I think this is as bad as giving the full answer from the beginning. Not downvoting though

Comment: @Oscar Possible, one could argue that the real assignment were to come up with an algorithm in which case you're right. Ah I'd make a horrible teacher :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to count each character it both array. If every character in array two has a higher count than its counterpart in array one then return true, else return false.